# How to set form action to open new window with certain size?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, window

So I use code like:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" target="foo" onSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=450,height=300,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')">
```

But it probubly will not work if user has JS disabeld. So how to set new window Width and height not using JS?

I know we can use  `target="_blank"` to open what I need in new window but size... I just cant find how to do such thing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a non-JavaScript way available to to this.

There's just not another way available to ensure a certain size.  The `target` to target a certain window is all you have available, but you can't size it like `window.open()` can.